# APACHE IMPALA SQL Average calculating

Tags: sql, impala

I need help to calculate the average of picks/lines by an area.
AREA = CLASSIFICATION_NAME 
PICKS/Lines = PICKS

The average should be an hourly average.

- 'Last Hour'
- 'Today'
- 'Daily AVG'

**I have an Article Table:**

```
| ARTICLE_ID | CLASSIFICATION_NAME |
| ---------- | ------------------- |
| 1          | 15deg_A_class       |
| 2          | 15deg_B_class       |
| 3          | 15deg_C_class       |
| 4          | 4deg_C_class        |
| 5          | frozen_manual_class |
```

**And I have a pick_table:**

```
|ID |Datetime           |Picks|Article|
|-- |-------------------|-----|-------|
|1  |16.05.2023 11:50:00|1    |1      |
|2  |16.05.2023 11:02:00|1    |3      |
|3  |16.05.2023 11:02:01|1    |3      |
|...|...                |...  |...    |
```

For each pick line which exists the column PICK is set with 1.
One day has about 40000 picks in all.

**I join this two tables like:**

```
SELECT
from_timestamp(to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS pick_date,
date_part('hour', to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS pick_hour,
CASE WHEN article.classification_name LIKE '15deg_%' THEN pick_table.picks END AS '15DEG',
pick_table.picks AS picks
FROM
pick_table
JOIN article ON article.id = pick_table.article;
```

**I tried to get the average like:**

```
SELECT
date_part('hour', to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS pick_hour,
AVG(CASE WHEN article.classification_name LIKE '15deg_%' THEN pick_table.picks END) AS '15DEG'
FROM
pick_table
JOIN article ON article.id = pick_table.article
GROUP BY date_part('hour', to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
ORDER BY date_part('hour', to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) desc;
```

And also tried it like:

```
WITH test AS(
SELECT
from_timestamp(to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS pick_date,
    date_part('hour', to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS pick_hour,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN article.classification_name LIKE '15deg_%' THEN picks END) AS '15DEG',
    SUM(CASE     
        WHEN article.classification_name LIKE '4deg_%' THEN picks END) AS '4DEG',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN article.classification_name LIKE 'frozen%' THEN picks END) AS 'FROZEN',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN article.classification_name LIKE '15deg_A%' THEN picks END) AS 'A',
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN article.classification_name LIKE '15deg_B%' THEN picks END) AS 'B',
    pick_table.picks AS picks
FROM pick_table
JOIN article ON article.id = pick_table.article
GROUP BY
from_timestamp(to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'),
date_part('hour', to_timestamp(CONCAT(substr(pick_table.datetime,1,10),' ', substr(pick_table.datetime,12,8)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')),
picks)
SELECT
pick_hour,
AVG(15DEG) AS '15DEG',
AVG(4DEG) AS '4DEG',
AVG(FROZEN) AS 'FROZEN',
AVG(A) AS 'A',
AVG(B) AS 'B'
FROM test
WHERE substr(pick_date,1,10) >= '14.05.2023' AND substr(pick_date,1,10) < '15.05.2023' 
GROUP BY pick_hour
ORDER BY pick_hour desc;
```

I don't get the result I want to have.

**Result should be like:**

```
|Hour|15DEG|4DEG|FROZEN|A  |B   |
|----|-----|----|------|---|----|
|0   |2560 |500 |0     |150|1200|
|1   |3750 |480 |1     |120|1150|
|... |...  |... |...   |...|... |
```

**And at least in front end I would have an output like:**

```
|Average  |15DEG|4DEG|FROZEN|A  |B   |
|---------|-----|----|------|---|----|
|Last Hour|4032 |2667|377   |571|3928|
|Today    |3904 |2835|384   |573|3821|
|Daily AVG|3967 |2751|381   |562|3870|
```

How an I do that? Can anybody help me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on PostgreSQL, so you may have to adapt a little bit:

First, the test tables and data :

```
create table article as select * from (values
(1, '15deg_A_class'),
(2, '15deg_B_class'),
(3, '15deg_C_class'),
(4, '4deg_C_class'),
(5, 'frozen_manual_class')) l(article_id, classification_name);

select * from article;

 article_id | classification_name 
------------+---------------------
          1 | 15deg_A_class
          2 | 15deg_B_class
          3 | 15deg_C_class
          4 | 4deg_C_class
          5 | frozen_manual_class

create table pick_table as select * from (values
(1, '2023-05-16 11:50:00'::timestamp, 1, 1),
(2, '2023-05-16 11:02:00', 1, 3),
(3, '2023-05-16 11:02:01', 1, 3)) l(id, datetime, picks, article);

select * from pick_table;

 id |      datetime       | picks | article 
----+---------------------+-------+---------
  1 | 2023-05-16 11:50:00 |     1 |       1
  2 | 2023-05-16 11:02:00 |     1 |       3
  3 | 2023-05-16 11:02:01 |     1 |       3
```

The trick is to group by classification and hour like that :

```
select substring(a.classification_name, 1, 5) as the_class,
       date_trunc('HOUR', datetime) as the_hour,
       sum(picks) nbpicks
from pick_table p join article a on a.article_id = p.article
group by the_class, the_hour

 the_class |      the_hour       | nbpicks 
-----------+---------------------+---------
 15deg     | 2023-05-16 11:00:00 |       3
```

You have also different types of aggregation that overlap each other, so we also need the following query to build the result set for A and B columns:

```
select substring(a.classification_name, 1, 7) as the_class,
       date_trunc('HOUR', datetime) as the_hour,
       sum(picks) nbpicks
from pick_table p join article a on a.article_id = p.article
where a.classification_name like '15deg%'
group by the_class, the_hour

 the_class |      the_hour       | nbpicks 
-----------+---------------------+---------
 15deg_A   | 2023-05-16 11:00:00 |       1
 15deg_C   | 2023-05-16 11:00:00 |       2
```

Then using the result set composed of those two results set above, we pivot it to compute the stats :

```
with X as (select substring(a.classification_name, 1, 5) as the_class,
                  date_trunc('HOUR', datetime) as the_hour,
                  sum(picks) nbpicks
           from pick_table p join article a on a.article_id = p.article
           group by the_class, the_hour
           union all
           select substring(a.classification_name, 1, 7) as the_class,
                  date_trunc('HOUR', datetime) as the_hour,
                  sum(picks) nbpicks
           from pick_table p join article a on a.article_id = p.article
           where a.classification_name like '15deg%'
           group by the_class, the_hour)
select 'Last Hour',
       sum(case when the_class = '15deg' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "15DEG",
       sum(case when the_class = '4deg_' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "4DEG",
       sum(case when the_class = 'froze' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "FROZEN",
       sum(case when the_class = '15deg_A' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "A",
       sum(case when the_class = '15deg_B' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "B"
from X
where the_hour = date_trunc('HOUR', now() - interval '1' hour)
union all
select 'Today',
       avg(case when the_class = '15deg' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "15DEG",
       avg(case when the_class = '4deg_' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "4DEG",
       avg(case when the_class = 'froze' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "FROZEN",
       avg(case when the_class = '15deg_A' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "A",
       avg(case when the_class = '15deg_B' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "B"
from X
where date_trunc('DAY', the_hour) = date_trunc('DAY', now())
union all
select 'Daily AVG',
       avg(case when the_class = '15deg' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "15DEG",
       avg(case when the_class = '4deg_' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "4DEG",
       avg(case when the_class = 'froze' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "FROZEN",
       avg(case when the_class = '15deg_A' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "A",
       avg(case when the_class = '15deg_B' then nbpicks else 0 end) as "B"
from X;
```

Comment: thank you for the perfect and detailed answer. I have one question, why is there a 'SUM' for 'LAST HOUR' and 'AVG' for all other rows? Should not be all of them 'AVG'?

Comment: For 'Last Hour', normally there's only one row to SUM as this is a total per hour : so using SUM or AVG is the same. But it conceptually pleases me more to use SUM in case there are many rows, as each row should represents the same hour, and not different hours to be averaged : so in theory you should add all picks instead of averaging. But that's a point a view.

Comment: but the output with SUM is much higher than with AVG so something is not clear to me.